# Performance of data streaming from file vs directory of files

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, gensim

I am using word2vec from Gensim and I am feeding sentences to the model with the following iterator:

```
class SentencesIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = source

        if os.path.isdir(self.source):
            self.type_source = 'dir'
        else:
            self.type_source = 'file'

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.type_source == 'dir':
            for fname in os.listdir(self.source):
                with open(os.path.join(self.source, fname)) as f:
                    for line in f:
                        yield line.split()
        else:
            with open(self.source) as f:
                    for line in f:
                        yield line.split()
```

Everything is working as expected but I noticed that the performance varies a lot depending on the type of input.

For a single file in input:
`INFO : PROGRESS: at 5.43% examples, 73483 words/s`

For a directory with 1 file: `INFO : PROGRESS: at 17.09% examples, 71716 words/s`

For a directory with 2 files: `INFO : PROGRESS: at 11.62% examples, 67678 words/s`

For a directory with 30 files: `INFO : PROGRESS: at 1.19% examples, 54004 words/s`

I don't understand the decrease in the speed of streaming. To me, all the operations are identical, it is just about opening a file and reading it line by line..

PS: I tried with 4 cores and 1 core and the same behavior is observed!

Comment: Are you experimenting with exactly the same file (30 copies of it)? Do you do any other processing beyond reading?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same file indded!

Answer (score 0):

The **decrease in the speed** you are seeing, is the effect of caching files in the OS.

Successive reading the same file or files are results in reading form the OS cache instead of reading from HDD.